# Batch File | Dividing Variables by another

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm wondering how you would subtract a variable from another if you were wanting to execute something a few times.

I have the looping function embedded into my code but do not know if that is affecting the rest of the code.

Code:

```
set /a cash=1500

:cashfarm.loop
cls
echo [ Cash ] - [%cash%]
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo [ b ] - (to go back to screen menu.)

set /a cash=%cash%+%lvl%/3
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

goto cashfarm.loop
```

And when I run the file, it runs perfectly, until I get to the above step.

Comment: This is very badly asked.  If you want to ask about arithmetic with variables or regular numbers, then look up and ask about that, don't show a program with a loop

Comment: I have looked this up many times, and have not found success in doing so. Now if you could please just leave a way to solve my problem or direct someone to me, then that would be splendid. Otherwise, goodbye.

Comment: This website is not just for you, so it's important to ask a good question, as a question should be useful to others too.  A loop is not relevant to your question.  Unless you think you know how to divide one variable by another, in which case you should be clearer that you know how but you think the loop is breaking it for some reason.

Comment: not only have you asked a bad question, but you haven't troubleshooted at all, you haven't shown any evidence of troubleshooting. Your code runs even worse than what you showed if  people don't have the lvl variable set so you clearly didn't test your code from a fresh cmd prompt. You haven't explained about expected result. You've shown some ability to divide but no proper attempt to subtract..

Comment: so there is every sign that you just copy pasted this and have made no attempt at understanding it, no attempt at even trying to subtract in even the most basic way.  Also this question is not that suitable for superuser as it's a programming question, but it's even more unsuitable for stackoverflow because it is way below their quality standards

Comment: Do not worry, and I have NOT copied and pasted this, as I have made this code myself. On GOD. But I have found the solution to this problem. So thank you for NOT helping.

Comment: No problem. I also notice you didn't make any improvements to your question, despite the suggestions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should help.
First, when declaring a variable you don't add the user input instead you do this
`set cash=1500`
Let's say you were dividing 8 by 2 you would do this
`set num1=8 & set num2=2`
the 'set /a' input command is used to answer integers
`set /a math %num1/%num2%`
`echo %math%`
`pause`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this, I am sorry if it did not make any sense to you at first, like barlop said it didn't to him.